# What's the difference between getattr(self, '__a') and self.__a in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I thought they were the same before I ran this code:

```
class B(object):
    def show(self):
        self.__a = "test"
        print "B"

    def this_b(self):
        print "this_b"
        print self.__a
        print getattr(self, '__a') #exception


class C(B):
    def show(self):
        print "C"
        # B.show(self)
        super(C, self).show()


    def call(self):
        print "call"
        self.show()
        self.this_b()
        # print self.__a

C().call()
```

It raises `AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__a'` with the `getattr` statement, but why?

Comment: Because [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references).

Comment: In general, using `__`-prefixed attribute names is now discouraged in Python in favor of just a single underscore.

Comment: @ErikAllik: I'm not sure it was ever encouraged. It's always been available solely for variables that should be protected from accidental override in a derived class.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment meant; what I said was that such protection is not encouraged anymore.

Comment: @ErikAllik: nneonneo's point was it's never been supposed to be for general use. It was never encouraged in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because of the [Private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers).

> **Private name mangling:** When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used. If the transformed name is extremely long (longer than 255 characters), implementation defined truncation may happen. If the class name consists only of underscores, no transformation is done.

When you do

```
self.__a
```

Private name mangling will be taken care automatically. But when you do

```
print getattr(self, '__a')
```

you have to do it manually, like this

```
print getattr(self, '_B__a')
# test
```